# Implement step function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I try to implement a (restricted version of) step function in Haskell. A step functions is a function that is constant on a finite number of half intervals, and `mempty` everywhere else. (equivalently, one can fill those "everywhere else" by half intervals)

This can be modeled as a `StepData a b`, which stores a list of the half intervals and the associated value for that half interval. 
Not all `Ord a` has a minimum or maximum, I lift it to `Bound a`, which guaranties it to have a minimum and maximum, this is to make the algorithm clearer.

I implemented `eval :: StepData a b -> a -> b` to evaluate a step function at a point.

The important part is the ability to make step function a monoid, where `<>` is defined as pointwise sum of the function. Currently I implemented `<>` for the `StepData a b`.

P.S. Whenever I want to find a value, I have to run `eval f x`. Of course I can define `g = eval f`, but I can't use `<>` on the derived function. So I have to pass the data around in order to combine functions, and only call `eval` when I need to find a value. Are there better ways to handle this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-} 

import Data.List
import Data.Monoid

data Bound a = Minimum | Value a | Maximum  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data StepData x y = StepData [(Bound x, Bound x, y)] 
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance (Ord x, Monoid y) => Monoid (StepData x y) where
  mempty = StepData [(Minimum, Maximum, mempty)]
  mappend (StepData a) (StepData b) = StepData (foldl insertInterval b a)
    where
      insertInterval [] _ = []
      insertInterval ((a',b',y'):xs) (a,b,y) 
       | a >= b' = non [(a',b',y')] ++ insertInterval xs (a,b,y) 
       | b >= b' = non [(a',a,y'),(a,b',y <> y')] ++ insertInterval xs (b',b,y) 
       | b <  b' = non [(a',a,y'),(a,b, y <> y'),(b,b',y')] ++ xs
       where non = filter (\(a,b,_)-> a/=b)

      merge (h@(a,_,y):h'@(_,b',y'):xs)
       | y == y'   = merge ((a,b',y):xs)
       | otherwise = h:merge (h':xs)
      merge x = x

eval (StepData xs) t = y
  where (_,_,y) = head $ dropWhile sol xs
        sol (a,b,y)
         | a<=Value t && Value t<b = False
         | otherwise   = True

fromList xs = StepData (map (\(a,b,y)->(Value a, Value b, y)) xs) `mappend` mempty
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little bit late to the party, but better late than never, right?

## Type signatures

Your central functions `fromList` and `eval` don't have type signatures. This forces the user to check `Value` and `StepData`'s definition. Better add them:

```
eval :: Ord a => StepData a
eval = ...

fromList :: (Ord a, Monoid b) => [(a, a, b)]-> StepData a b
fromList  = ...
```

## Remove dead code

`merge` isn't used in your code. It's dead code and not used in your instance at all. Better remove it.

## Make sure the code compiles

That wasn't an issue back in 2013, but nowadays `Semigroup` is a superclass of `Monoid`, and you need to implement it too.

## Don't encode `Bool` twice

`eval`'s `sol` can be simplified a lot if we just use `not` around the condition:

```
eval (StepData xs) t = y
  where (_,_,y) = head $ dropWhile sol xs
        sol (a,b,_) = not (a <= Value t && Value t < b)
```

The function also gets easier to understand if we use `filter` instead, as we don't need to deal with double negation (`drop` and `not`):

```
eval (StepData xs) t = y
  where (_,_,y) = head $ filter sol xs
        sol (a,b,_) = a <= Value t && Value t < b
```

## Document requirements of data

`fromList` needs a proper sorted list. That's not documented anywhere and neither enforced in its type nor its logic. We might end up with `StepData [(Value 3, Value 1, Maybe 3)]` or `StepData [(Value 3, Value 4, Maybe 3),(Value 1, Value 2, Maybe 3)]`, as the list is only `map`ed.

Instead, use `foldMap` and make sure that the values are ordered properly:

```
fromList = foldMap go
  where
    go (a, b, y)
      | a < b     = StepData [(Value a, Value b, y)]
      | otherwise = StepData [(Value b, Value a, y)]
```